# Trying to create multiples small multi-dimensional arrays with malloc

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to allocate two multi-dimensional arrays from a struct with a function. Allocating the first works perfectly but the second fails, even though the code for the two arrays is *exactly the same*.

I thought it would be because I don't have enough memory, but I have 16GB of RAM and this doesn't even take a kilobyte.

If it can help I'm using CLion and C98. I also tried to launch the exported program without CLion in case it's coming from it.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "include/calc.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    calc calcObject = InitCalcObject();
}
```

**calc.h**

```
typedef struct CalculationObjectElement {
    int ** braketArray; // <--- First array, correct allocation
    int braketCount;
    int braketHighestPriority;

    int ** squareBraketArray; // <--- Second array, fails
    int squareBraketCount;
} CalculationObjectElement, *calc;

calc InitCalcObject();
```

**calc.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "include/calc.h"

calc InitCalcObject()
{
    calc calcReturn = malloc(sizeof(calcReturn));

    if (calcReturn == NULL) {
        FailureHandler("Malloc - Calc object");
        return NULL;
    }

    int i;

    calcReturn->braketArray = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 256); // Working great
    calcReturn->squareBraketArray = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 256); // Working great

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        calcReturn->braketArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); // Working like a charm

        if (calcReturn->braketArray[i] == NULL) {
            FailureHandler(strcat("Malloc - Calc object - braketArray", (char *) i));
            return NULL;
        }

        calcReturn->squareBraketArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); // Not working

        if (calcReturn->squareBraketArray[i] == NULL) { 
            FailureHandler(strcat("Malloc - Calc object - squareBraketArray", (char *) i));
            return NULL;
        } //There wasn't this failure handler at first, added it desperately trying to solve this
    }

    return calcReturn;
}
```

For sure, I'm trying to debug it and get :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
InitCalcObject () at F:\Codage\C\Projects\Calculator\src\calc.c:33
33          calcReturn->squareBraketArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
```

Two times before it just crashed (0xC0000005).

Comment: You are not checking the return value from `malloc`s above the loop. How do you do that things are, in fact, working and failing? are you stepping through in the debugger? Using printf debugging that you haven't exhibited here?

Comment: *'//There wasn't this failure handler at first, added it desperatly trying to solve this"* Well, yes. It isn't that the line in question is returning a `NULL` value; it's crashing because of something that happened *before* you got there.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm stepping through the debugger... Haven't done the printf debugging, but with the gdb debugger I see the index (i) at 0, this mean that it can't even allocate the first element of the 2d array and that's where it's crashing...
**Edit** : Yeah I don't even know why I added this function it's not even working ^^ **Edit 2** : I've just tried to check the malloc of the first dimension of the array, working perfeclty...

Comment: I don't know my `typedef`/comma rules well enough,, but this line is wrong: `calc calcReturn = malloc(sizeof(calcReturn));` You must be hiding a pointer in the `typedef`, and so `sizeof(calcReturn)` is going to allocate the size of a pointer only (4 or 8 bytes depending on your architecture). In this case you want to allocate the size of the entire structure, either `sizeof(CalculationObjectElement)` or `sizeof(*calcReturn)`.

Comment: Hi Yano, It's not actually the problem, and it's not what I want, but thanks you, haven't though of that before :) It's the second 2d array that doesn't want to allocate while the first works perfectly...

Comment: `strcat("Malloc - Calc object - squareBraketArray", (char *) i)` - this will never work

Comment: that is certainly _a_ problem. You're not allocating nearly enough space. Every `calcReturn->` is an offset from your allocated base address, you have at best 8 bytes there. Doesn't take long before you touch memory you don't own, in this case that appears to be at `calcReturn->squareBracket`. You're invoking undefined behavior by accessing memory you don't own. If you want to use a `sizeof` parameter in `malloc`, it needs to be "one level up" from the pointer you want to assign to, ie `int* myIntPtr = malloc(45 * sizeof(*myIntPtr));`

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: You also need to understand that concept of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). When you invoke UB, anything can happen, including appearing to "work perfectly". But it may not work next time, or on your buddy's machine, or when you change compiler flags/optimizations, or when you use another compiler entirely, etc. Your violation is closest to Program 4 here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/undefined-behavior-c-cpp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Yano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476780/yano), I finally found the solution, and man it's ridiculous... I'm posting this answer so everyone that fall on this and has the same problem can fix it.

As Yano said in the comments under the answer, I haven't allocated all the space for the struct, but only a pointer to it...

I don't know how I made this mistake, maybe I should go to sleep xD

So if you did like me, a typedef of a struct with a pointer (This mean that your typedef replaces structElement by *structElement) you need to be sure to allocate not the pointer for the struct, but all the pointers and variables inside the struct, this means the struct itself.
So if you do a malloc() with a sizeof(), do not do it with the pointer of it (Si the typedef you did).

Here's an example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Creating the struct //
typedef struct structElement { 
    int Var1;
    int ** TwoDimensionsArray;
    float Var2;
} structElement, *pointerStructElement; 
// Doing a typedef so pointerStructElement means a pointer of the structElement itself

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pointerStructElement structTest; // Declaring a POINTER of the struct
    
    if (structTest = malloc(sizeof(structElement)) == NULL) {
       printf("structTest couldn't be allocated.");
       exit(1);
    }
    /* 
       Allocating memory for the size of the struct and NOT the pointer of the 
       struct, it's where I got it wrong at first
    */
    
    printf("structTest correctly allocated !!!");

    free(structTest);

    return 0;
}
```

I really hope I helped some people with that, pointers are hards things to understand and you can always make small mistakes like that.

Thank you again Yano :)

Have a great day,
Jules.

PS: Also thanks to everyone else for your help :)